# Regular expression in Perl with case insensitivity

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following text pattern,

> os2v some text openssl-56 test Is Not founded

and need to extract the word before "test Is Not founded", i.e., in this case: `openssl-56`

Currently I've tried to use this regular expression:

```
if (m/os2v (\s+) test is NOT founded/i){
    print $1
}
```

But why does the code not enter the *if* statement?

Comment: Revision 3 (2011-11-10T134953Z+0) invalidated the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious problems are that your text doesn't include the word "Update" and `\s` will match **whitespace**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't get a match since your pattern is incorrect. The following pattern would match and extract `openssl-56` for you:

```
(\S+)(?=\stest Is Not founded)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
m/os2v .*\s([^\s]+) test is NOT founded/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the space before and after (*\s+*).